# Repository to execute Doctrine Dbal queries inside module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

My goal is to be able to execute SQL queries from inside a PS 1.7.4.2 module. It is encouraged form the docs to use Doctrine Dbal services.

From the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/use-hooks-on-modern-pages/#using-doctrine-dbal-to-retrieve-data):

> Even if using old way to retrieve data is still valid
>   (Product::getProducts or through the webservice), we’d like to
>   introduce a best practice here: using a repository and get ride of the
>   Object model. This has a lot of advantages, you rely on database
>   instead of model and you’ll have better performances and control on
>   your data.

I don't think it respects PS philosophy if I put the repository class in `src/Prestashop/Entity/Repository`.So where to put the repository class?

Comment: First at all, version 1.7.5.4 still does not exist. And about to use the DB object in a module you doesn't need to add any custom file in the `/src`

Comment: @Rolige. My bad, I corrected it . Thank you for answering. I agree that I can use the DB object inside module, but I need to use the Doctrine DBAL since it is recommended by the docs. Kind  of moving Symfony. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to render something in some of the new modern pages of the back office?

Comment: @Rolige, Yes. I am trying to add an extra field in Product backoffice page, but before, I want to update database schema by adding a column in ps_product. A working solution is to use `Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql)` for this later matter. I just want to use the solution provided in docs (not well explained IMHO)

Comment: You are in the wrong way, first at all you never should modify the structure of a base table because you are killing future upgrades. If you want to add an extra field in the product, you need do this with your own additional tables.

Comment: Really???!!!  The module I am creating will add the column to DB using `install` and  will remove it  at `uninstall`, which is a common practice in creating modules that interacts with databases (according many tuto). Well, creating an  additionnal table seems good idea. How to do with Doctrine DBAL inside module ? Thanks again

Comment: Uff, I think you need read a lot of documentation to create a module, how it should be hooked according to your needs, etc, etc, I can’t explain you a full creation of a module is something crazy. And if you want some advice, I recommend you start with the simple, which is not to create it with the new doctrine. You can also support you with many modules that are included in the PrestaShop as well as the online documentation.

Comment: @Rolige, I already created the module without Doctrine. I want to use modern way of creating module, using Repository as a service that I can get anywhere  with Symfony Service container. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Has anyone managed to implement this: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/use-hooks-on-modern-pages/#using-doctrine-dbal-to-retrieve-data   ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by executing `composer init` inside module and mapping `src` in module to `Foo` namespace.

Then inside module files, you can access services from the container, i.e Doctrine services.

You can additionnaly define your own Repository classes as services and get them from the container.

Comment: So where to put the repository class? :)